# Rails - FATAL: database "myapp_development" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to set up my Env to use PostgreSQL with Rails and i followed the steps to install PostgreSQL from this [Article](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite#database)

Am getting the following error

> ATAL: database "myapp_development" does not exist Extracted source
>   (around line #661):

```
rescue ::PG::Error => error
if error.message.include?("does not exist")
raise ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError.new(error.message, error)
else
raise
end
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Did you run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate` before `rails server`?

#### UPDATE

Here's all the steps you should do:

1. `cd /your/app/path`
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle exec rake db:create`
4. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
5. `bundle exec rails server`

Comment: getting this error rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rake'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Do u have rake gem in ur Gemfile?  Check the output of this  ' gem list rake'

Comment: @Hemali `rails` depend on `railties`, which depend on `rake`. So apparently yes.

Comment: Yes it's does have railties. But I felt if rails versions are mis configured. Usually this error occurs when version difference are there. Try Deleting gemfile.lock and running bundle install

Comment: I was getting mysql error, and this one worked for me ! :)

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
rails db:create
```

before running

```
rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also create PostgreSQL database manually by using psql command prompt.

When in there, connect to your local server and write "create database myapp_development;" without the quotes

Comment: when i try to go onto psql command prompt i am getting the following error. psql: FATAL:  database "harshamv" does not exist

Comment: can you please tell me how i can login to psql command prompt

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. I checked different websites and tried what they suggested but didn't work. Then I tried  `rake db:create:all` and rake `db:migrate` it worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by:
`bundle exec rake db:setup`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to provide what the error said.."create the database that does not exist"....I spent many hours trying different commands or run db:migrate using bundle but none of that worked. I thought it should create the db on it's own but no...I eventually decided to create the db in postgres

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
CREATE DATABASE tableNameFromDatabase.yml WITH OWNER myusername;
```

after this rails db:migrate worked